# text extraction multiple variables using rsplit

Tags: python, text-extraction

I am trying to split the content of a string into separate strings in a list. for that I used the following code

```
A='27_D | 27_B & 52_E'
B = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PL_HFG'])
print(contains_all(A, '|&'))
C=A.replace('&', '').replace('|', '')
print(C)
D=C.rsplit(" ",1)
print(D)
```

The final printed output is `['27_D  27_B ', '52_E']`. What I want to have is `['27_D, 27_B ', '52_E']`. If you look closely you would see that 27_D and 27_B are separated in the wanted case. But in my case they are put together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple approach (no `rsplit` needed):

```
a = '27_D | 27_B & 52_E'
b = [i for i in a.split() if '_' in i]
print(b)
```

It splits the `str` by spaces, and then creates a `list` only with the elements that contain an *underscore*.

Output:

```
['27_D', '27_B', '52_E']
```